# Scrape a table iterating over pages of a website: how to define the last page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, web-scraping

I have the following code that works OK:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

df_list = []
for i in range(1, 13):
    url = 'https://www.uzse.uz/trade_results?date=25.01.2019&mkt_id=ALL&page=%d' %i
    df_list.append(pd.read_html(url)[0])

df = pd.concat(df_list)
df
```

But for this particular page I know the number of pages, which is 13 in `range(1, 13)`. Is there a way to define the last page so I do not have to go and check how many pages there are on a given page?

Comment: Using try except break

Comment: can you pls elaborate? because the when `page=14` there is no error reported. I just get an empty table.

Comment: added let me know whether it work for you or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
for i in range(1, 100):

    url = 'https://www.uzse.uz/trade_results?date=25.01.2019&mkt_id=ALL&page=%d' %i
    if pd.read_html(url)[0].empty:
        break
    else :
        df_list.append(pd.read_html(url)[0])
```

---

```
page=0                    # using while
while page > 0:
   url = 'https://www.uzse.uz/trade_results?date=25.01.2019&mkt_id=ALL&page=%d' % i
   df_list.append(pd.read_html(url)[0])
   page = page + 1
   if pd.read_html(url)[0].empty:
      break

print(page)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know the number of pages, which is 13 in `range(1, 13)`.

You seem to be suffering from an OBOB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). Put a `print(i)` in your loop and you'll see it counts from 1 up to 12.

You may be happier with:

```
for i in range(13):
```

and then use the expression `... % (i + 1)`.

Cf https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range

Answer (score 1):

For this particular website, you could detect the number of pages from the pagination bar. You can use something similar to the following code snippet:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.uzse.uz/trade_results?date=25.01.2019&mkt_id=ALL')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
lastpage_url = soup.find("li", {"class": "last next"}).findChildren("a")[0]['href']
num_pages = int(lastpage_url[lastpage_url.rfind("=")+1:])
```

Comment: Very interesting, will give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped!